# TargetDataLine.getFramePosition() vs read()

Tags: java, api, audio

What does "current" frame position actually mean? This does not described in documentation.

If I have just read some buffer from TargetDataLine and after that have called getFramePosition -- then this will be the position of

1. first
2. last
3. other

frame in the readen buffer?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation:

> Obtains the current position in the
>   audio data, in sample frames. The
>   frame position measures the number of
>   sample frames captured by, or rendered
>   from, the line since it was opened.
>   This return value will wrap around
>   after 2^31 frames. It is recommended
>   to use getLongFramePosition instead.

It would appear to me it would be the first frame since it counts since the line was opened.

Also, I would like to point out that the API specifies that `getLongFramePosition` is recommended to be used instead.

Comment: Have you read about TargetDataLine.read(byte[] b, int off, int len) method? Documentation says you can read any portion of internal buffer. For example, internal buffer can contain 1000 frames but you can read 10. It will be first 10 then, i.e. from 0 to 9. Next you read 10 frames it will be from 10 to 19 and so on. Since you cannot control reading position, it is controlled internally. Also the "tail" should be known internally. Hence TargetDataLine is FIFO for bytes. And this means that frameposition may refer both head and tail of FIFO. Whichever is unknown from documentation!

Comment: @Dims, Which are you asking about?  I am confused as this comment doesn't match your question?

Comment: My question is about relationship between frame number (as returned by both getFramePostition() and getLongFramePosition()) and numbers of frames as returned by read(). I need to figure this out experimentally.